# Finding "chains" of numbers in a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

To give some context, this problem is related to music theory.

I have a matrix I'm generating with this code:

```
row = {0, 5, 8, 1, 4, 9, 2, 7, 11, 3, 6, 10};
m = Table[row[[j]] - row[[i]], {i, 1, 12}, {j, 1, 12}];
m // MatrixForm
```

(Note `row` can be any permutation of integers from 0 to 11 starting with 0.)

I want to find all the "chains" or "snakes" of numbers in the outputted matrix made by connecting adjacent numbers that differ by less than some delta. Basically, all the paths that exist on the matrix where each node differs by less than some number. Here is an example of some "chains" or "snakes" with delta <= 2 I found by hand in the matrix generated from `row = {0, 5, 8, 1, 4, 9, 2, 7, 11, 3, 6, 10}`:

[image]

Obviously, you have the trivial "chain" or "snake" of zeroes of the diagonal, but then you have the rest of them. I don't know where to go from here. I don't know how to represent the matrix, and then what functions to use to find the "chains" or "snakes." If I can just output them as a list of lists, that would be fine.

Comment: Interesting question!  We probably need a few more details about how you want to handle certain cases, though:  How do you want to handle the cycles (loops) in your graph?  Can a "chain" contain the same number more than once?   (Note that if you have a cycle in your graph, and you can repeat numbers, then the number of paths is infinite, since you can loop around the cycle an arbitrarily large number of times.)  Can a chain double back on itself?  Does a "chain" have to be maximal, or could I (for example) start at the 3 in the middle of your green "snake" and end at the -1 in the pink one?

Comment: This is interesting. I'd like to learn how it relates to music theory. Can you provide a brief explanation or a reference to that information?

Comment: @Ralph Dratman https://jan.ucc.nau.edu/krr2/12tone/12tone1.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Maybe someone can build on this to actually get all such paths, but in the meantime, here's something to get you started! Here's how you can get a graph whose vertices are elements of the matrix at position $i,j$ (in the form `{{i, j}, value}`) and whose edges connect neighbors whose absolute difference is less than or equal to some `delta`:

```
(* turn a matrix into a list of elements of the form {{i, j}, value}: *)

flattenindex[mat_] := Flatten[MapIndexed[{#2, #1} &, mat, {2}], 1]

(* get a list of undirected edges: *)

dneighbors[mat_, delta_] := 
 UndirectedEdge @@@ 
  Select[Subsets[flattenindex[mat], {2}], 
   Norm[First@First[#] - First@Last[#], Infinity] == 1 && 
     Abs[Last@First[#] - Last@Last[#]] <= delta &]

(* view the graph with vertex labels of the form value_position: *)

g = dneighbors[m, 2];

Graph[g, VertexLabels -> {x_ :> Subscript[Last[x], Sequence @@ First[x]]}]
```

[image: the output of the first evaluation of Graph]

```
(* view the graph with values in their "matrix" positions: *)

Graph[g, VertexLabels -> {x_ :> Last[x]},
  VertexCoordinates -> ({#2, -#1} & @@ First[#] &) /@ VertexList[g]]
```

[image: the output of the second evaluation of Graph]
There are more efficient non-`Select` ways of doing this, but since your matrix is small, it should be ok.

One could maybe actually get a list of all chains exhaustively by evaluating `FindPath[g, v0, v1, Infinity, All]` for all pairs of vertices `v0` and `v1` in the resulting graph `g`, and then removing all paths that are not maximal—but I expect there's a better way!

Comment: That's awesome. Wonderful stuff. Just a very minor comment. There's a missing bracket in the Graph command at the end.

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0 ah, thank you very much! I had copied it in two parts and missed it. :)

Comment: `NearestGraph` or `RelationGraph` might come in handy.

Comment: ah, `RelationGraph` is cleaner, but it leaves in vertices that are not connected to anything! for what it's worth, though, here's what that would look like: `dneighbors[mat_, delta_] := RelationGraph[
 Norm[First@#1 - First@#2, Infinity] == 1 && 
   Abs[Last@#1 - Last@#2] <= delta &, flattenindex[mat]]`

Answer (score 8):

Following up on [thorimur's excellent answer,](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/245944/27813) here's some code that appears to work once you have defined the graph `g` in that answer.  It can probably be optimized quite a bit more than its current state;  in particular, I still don't quite know why I had to invoke `Flatten` twice in one command.

The heart of this is the `FindPath` function, which does not appear to allow for repeated vertices.  If you want to handle loops differently, or allow for doubling back, then this code won't work.

```
(* Define a minimum and maximum length for the paths we're interested in *)
minlength = 5;
maxlength = Infinity;

(* Find all the connected components of the graph *)
components = ConnectedComponents[g];

(* Find all the pairs of endpoints of each components, i.e., vertices of degree 1. *)
(* Note that a "maximal" chain must go from one such vertex to another such vertex. *)
endpoints[comp_] := Select[comp, VertexDegree[g, #] == 1 &]
Flatten[Flatten[Subsets[endpoints[#], {2}] & /@ components, {2}], 1]

(* Find all the paths between the pairs of vertices we found above. *)
(* This output can be quite long if minlength is small. *)
paths = Flatten[FindPath[g, #[[1]], #[[2]], {minlength, maxlength}, All] & /@ %, 1]

(* Display the paths *)

HighlightGraph[g, PathGraph[#], VertexCoordinates -> ({#2, -#1} & @@ First[#] &) /@ VertexList[g]] & /@ paths
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

To select over a table `tab`the elements differing from `base` for `delta` showing them in clusters.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
selection[tab_List, ref_, delta_] := 
 Module[{list = {}, select = {}, n = Length[tab], m, i, j, knot, i0, j0},
  For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
   For[j = 1, j <= n, j++,
    AppendTo[list, {tab[[i, j]], i, j}]
    ]
   ];
  m = Length[list];
  For[i = 1, i <= m, i++,
   If[Abs[ref - list[[i, 1]]] <=  delta, 
    {knot, i0, j0} = list[[i]];
    AppendTo[select, {i0, j0}]
    ]
   ];
  Return[select]
  ]

mdist[elem_, pool_List] := Module[{i}, 
 For[i = 1, i <= Length[pool], i++,
   If[Max[Abs[pool[[i]] - elem]] == 1 , Return[True]]
   ];
  Return[False]
  ]

Clear[contiguous]
contiguous[select_List] := Module[{prox, i, select1, lenant = 0},
  select1 = select;
  prox = {select1[[1]]};
  While[Length[prox] > lenant,
   lenant = Length[prox];
   select1 = Complement[select1, prox];
   For[i = 1, i <= Length[select1], i++,
    If[mdist[select1[[i]], prox],
     AppendTo[prox, select1[[i]]];
     ]
    ]
   ];
  Return[prox]
  ]
```

The main procedure

```
row = {0, 5, 8, 1, 4, 9, 2, 7, 11, 3, 6, 10};
n = 12;
tab = Table[row[[j]] - row[[i]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
base = 1;
delta = 2;
select = selection[tab, base, delta];
islands = {};
While[Length[select] > 0,
 prox = contiguous[select];
 AppendTo[islands, prox];
 select = Complement[select, prox]
 ]
```

And finally the graphic representation

```
classes = Table[0, n, n];
For[i = 1, i <= Length[islands], i++, prox = islands[[i]]; 
 np = Length[prox]; 
 If[np > 1, 
  For[j = 1, j <= Length[prox], j++, {i0, j0} = prox[[j]]; 
   classes[[i0, j0]] = i]]]
gr0 = ArrayPlot[classes, Mesh -> True, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];
numbers = Graphics[{Red, Table[Text[StringJoin[ToString /@ {tab[[n - i + 1, j]]}], {j - 0.5, i - 0.5}], {j, 1, n}, {i, 1, n}]}];
Show[gr0, numbers]
```

For `base = 1` and `delta = 2`

[image]

and for `base = 0` and `delta = 2`

[image]

and finally, for `base = 2` and `delta = 2`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This interesting question doesn't let me go.

I tried to solve the problem using  `FindClusters` (Thanks @flinty 's comment)

```
clus =FindClusters[flattenindex[m], 
DistanceFunction -> (Which[ChessboardDistance[First[#1 ], First[#2]] == 1 &&Norm[Last[#1] - Last[#2 ]] <= 2, 0, True, 1]  & )]
```

The result

```
Graphics[Table[{RandomColor[],   Point@clusi[[All, 1]]},{clusi,clus }], GridLines -> {Range[1, 12], Range[1, 12]}]
```

[image]

unfortunately contains all clusters found.

Is it possible to select only the sub-clusters with `DistanceFunction==0` ?

Thanks!

Comment: Your distance function has == and && in it, so it's a boolean expression and doesn't return a number.

Comment: @flinty Thanks, that means I have to look for  suitable DistanceFunction